# cats 2.2.0 implicit resolution from trait issue

Tags: scala, import, implicit, scala-cats

I'm trying the latest version of cats that is gearing toward the implicit scope rather than lexical scope. I'm not sure this is really relevant to my question, but felt like mentioning the version of cats as it might be related.

So i am simply with type class syntax

When i write the following:

```
import cats.Eq
import cats.syntax.eq._
1 === 1
```

Everything work and the resolution works perfectly as 2.2.0 claims. No need to import the instances.

My question actually about object vs Trait Import.

If i change the import of the syntax to the trait directly it does not work and i wonder why

```
import cats.Eq
import cats.syntax.EqSyntax

1 === 1
```

This does not work, however we have:

```
package cats
package syntax

trait EqSyntax {

  /**
   * not final so it can be disabled in favor of scalactic equality in tests
   */
  implicit def catsSyntaxEq[A: Eq](a: A): EqOps[A] =
    new EqOps[A](a)
}

final class EqOps[A: Eq](lhs: A) {
  def ===(rhs: A): Boolean = Eq[A].eqv(lhs, rhs)
  def =!=(rhs: A): Boolean = Eq[A].neqv(lhs, rhs)
  def eqv(rhs: A): Boolean = Eq[A].eqv(lhs, rhs)
  def neqv(rhs: A): Boolean = Eq[A].neqv(lhs, rhs)
}
```

So I was expecting the implicit to be in scope !

Meanwhile i found this:

```
package cats

package object syntax {
....
....
..
object eq extends EqSyntax
..
....
....
}
```

Hence i suspect it has to do with the implicit rules, but not sure.

Any idea ?

Comment: This: `import cats.syntax.EqSyntax` just imports that **trait** into scope, not the implicit conversions. You can `object Foo extends EqSyntax { 1 === 1 }` since now inside the body of the object the implicit conversion in scope.

Comment: Right right my bad it is not a static method :) !

Comment: Is not about it being static or not, is about scope. You can also import the `eq` **object**, the implicit conversions still won't be in scope, you need to import them from the object itself.

Comment: Yeah well you can’t import the content of a trait ? Can you ?  This does not compile ` cats.syntax.EqSyntax._` does not compile. That’s what I meant

Comment: Yeah of course, but my point was that importing something that has implicit conversions inside it do not put those implicit conversions into scope.

Comment: I understand! In any case, thanks for the answer! It helped.